# How to save file in iOS files app downloads folder in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, file, download, save

I want to save a file in iOS downloads folder so that it can be visible to user can you help me out please suggest me the latest iOS version flutter code and permissions to do so.

Tried adding UISupportsDocumentBrowser

UIFilesharingenabled

OpenDocumentsInPlace

But yet it is not saving to downloads folder but in my app sandbox directory if I cannot save in downloads folder can you tell me how can I make my app sandbox directory visible to user also can you suggest me file manager for flutter for this which is up to date and with a custom path on 2023?